# IOS: HTTPRequest to download a pdf file

Tags: ios, asihttprequest, home-directory

I have a problem in my app.

I'm using ASIHttpRequest to download a pdf file with this code:

```
- (void) downloadPdf{
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
if (currentDownload) {

    [currentDownload clearDelegatesAndCancel];
    currentDownload = nil;
    totalWorker = 0;
    [workers release]; workers = nil;
    progressView.progress = 0.0;

} else {

    [self removeFile];

    appDelegate.alertGlobal   = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Download file..."
                                                 message: @""
                                                delegate: self
                                       cancelButtonTitle: @"Annul"
                                       otherButtonTitles: nil];

    progressView = [[UIProgressView alloc] initWithFrame:
                    CGRectMake(30.0f, 43.0f, 225.0f, 10.0f)];
    [appDelegate.alertGlobal addSubview:progressView];
    [progressView setProgressViewStyle: UIProgressViewStyleBar];

    [appDelegate.alertGlobal show];

    NSString *tmp = @"http://192.168.0.13:8888/file.pdf";

    currentDownload = [[HappyDownload alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:tmp]];
    currentDownload.numberOfWorkers = totalWorker;
    currentDownload.totalChunk = 1;
    currentDownload.delegate = self;
    currentDownload.downloadProgressDelegate = self;
    currentDownload.allowResumeForFileDownloads = YES;

    documentsDirectory = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];

    [currentDownload setDownloadDestinationPath:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"file.pdf"]];

    [workers removeAllObjects];

    [currentDownload startAsynchronous];

    start = [NSDate new];
}
}



- (void) removeFile{

    NSString *pathTemp = [NSHomeDirectory()stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
    //NSString *path = [pathTemp stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"file.pdf"];

    NSFileManager* fm = [[[NSFileManager alloc] init] autorelease];
    NSDirectoryEnumerator* en = [fm enumeratorAtPath:pathTemp];
    NSError* err = nil;
    BOOL res;

    NSString* file;
    while (file = [en nextObject]) {
        res = [fm removeItemAtPath:[pathTemp stringByAppendingPathComponent:file] error:&err];
        if (!res && err) {
            NSLog(@"error: %@", err);
        }
    }

}



-(void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request{
    NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSSecondCalendarUnit
                                                              fromDate:start
                                                                toDate:[[NSDate new] autorelease]
                                                               options:0];
    int duration  = [comps second];

    NSLog(@"request finished, duration:%d", duration);

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    appDelegate.downloaded = TRUE;

    [currentDownload clearDelegatesAndCancel];
    currentDownload = nil;
    totalWorker = 0;
    [workers release]; workers = nil;
    progressView.progress = 0.0;

    [appDelegate.alertGlobal dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
    [appDelegate.alertGlobal release];

    downloadedFirstTime = TRUE;

    NSError *error;
    NSString *pathTemp = [NSHomeDirectory()stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSLog(@"Documents directory: %@", [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:pathTemp error:&error]);

    [self openFile];

}

- (void) requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    [currentDownload clearDelegatesAndCancel];
    currentDownload = nil;
    totalWorker = 0;
    [workers release]; workers = nil;
    progressView.progress = 0.0;

    [appDelegate.alertGlobal dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
    [appDelegate.alertGlobal release];

    NSLog(@"request failed");
    NSLog(@"Error %@", [request error]);
    int statusCode = [request responseStatusCode];
    NSString *statusMessage = [request responseStatusMessage];
    NSLog(@"statuscode:%d", statusCode);
    NSLog(@"statusmessage:%@", statusMessage);
}
```

OK in this way I download correctly a pdf file and I open it in this way with this control:

https://github.com/vfr/Reader

the classic controller to open pdf file in iPhone and I use this method:

```
- (void) openFile{

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

    NSString *phrase = nil; // Document password (for unlocking most encrypted PDF files)

    NSString *pathTemp = [NSHomeDirectory()stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
    NSString *path = [pathTemp stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"file.pdf"];

    assert(path != nil); // Path to last PDF file

    ReaderDocument *document = [ReaderDocument withDocumentFilePath:path password:phrase];

    if (document != nil) // Must have a valid ReaderDocument object in order to proceed
    {
        readerViewController = [[ReaderViewController alloc] initWithReaderDocument:document];

        readerViewController.delegate = self; // Set the ReaderViewController delegate to self

        //mainWindow.rootViewController = readerViewController; // Set the root view controller
    }

    [self presentModalViewController:readerViewController animated:YES];

    [readerViewController release];
}
```

It work fine the FIRTS TIME and I open a first file pdf without problems, but when I download a second different pdf that I upload on the server, I have a big problem...inside it I see two pdf file, one above the other, but I don't understand if the problem is the ASIHttpRequest or the readerViewController. As you can see I remove file inside HomeDirectory but I don't understand the problem, can you help me?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

At your remove method, have you checked the path(with file name) is correct? Also, try one more thing the place where you delete your file,after that check for existence of that file.

May be it give some idea.

Comment: yes it remove correctly the file, and I checked also the size of file that I open in openFile method at this path "NSString *path = [pathTemp stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"file.pdf"];", but it's ever the same size, it's correct

Comment: In your remove file what your pathTemp log, please tell.

Comment: NSString* file;
    while (file = [en nextObject]) {
        res = [fm removeItemAtPath:[pathTemp stringByAppendingPathComponent:file] error:&err];
        if (!res && err) {
            NSLog(@"error: %@", err);
        }
    } Check this here you're not providing the file name which you want to erase.

Comment: I added two nslog to check before and after I remove the file and result is: 2012-11-27 14:58:26.298 project[2690:907] Documents directory before: (
    "file.pdf"
)
2012-11-27 14:58:26.300 project[2690:907] error: (null)
2012-11-27 14:58:26.306 project[2690:907] Documents directory after: (
)